# Is there a way to make map over a Clojure vector of maps use a destructing bind?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, destructuring

I'm using this code:

```
 (println 
   (mapcat 
      (fn [my-map] 
        (str (:key my-map) (:value my-map) "\n")) 
      [{:key 1 :value 2}{:key 3 :value 4}]))
```

I think there is a way to make it shorter using a destructing bind.

My question is: **Is there a way to make map over a Clojure vector of maps use a destructing bind?**

Comment: are you asking if my-map can be destructured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the values directly in the function argument list:

```
(println
 (mapcat
  (fn [{k :key, v :value}]
    (str k v "\n"))
  [{:key 1 :value 2} {:key 3 :value 4}]))
```